# Confusion about getting color of a point on screen with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to get color value from a pixel on screen with a cocoa app. The idea is that app should be able to get a color value anywhere on the screen, even outside the scope of the app itself.

I did a bunch of research and this is essentially what I am doing

```
- (void) keepRunning:(NSTimer *)timer{

NSPoint mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation];

uint32_t count = 0;
CGDirectDisplayID displayForPoint;

if (CGGetDisplaysWithPoint(NSPointToCGPoint(mouseLoc), 1, &displayForPoint, &count) != kCGErrorSuccess)
{
    NSLog(@"Break");
    return;
}

CGImageRef image = CGDisplayCreateImageForRect(displayForPoint, CGRectMake(mouseLoc.x-10, mouseLoc.y-10, 1, 1));
NSBitmapImageRep* bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:image];
CGImageRelease(image);
NSColor* color = [bitmap colorAtX:0 y:0];
NSLog(@"%@", color);
```

}

keepRunning fires every 100 ms or so. This seems to be the correct way of doing this. Problem is, I don't get the correct color values. All values outputted are gray and basically wrong. Any ideas about what I am doing wrong? Is it something to do with transparency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code a bit and put it in my animation timer.  This seems to work.  Note that I'm only creating a 1 pixel image and I flipped the mouseLoc.y value.

```
CGFloat screenHeight = 900.0; // This is the display height of my machine

NSPoint mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation];

uint32_t count = 0;
CGDirectDisplayID displayForPoint;

if (CGGetDisplaysWithPoint(NSPointToCGPoint(mouseLoc), 1, &displayForPoint, &count) != kCGErrorSuccess)
{
    NSLog(@"Break");
    return;
}

CGImageRef image = CGDisplayCreateImageForRect(displayForPoint, CGRectMake(mouseLoc.x, screenHeight - mouseLoc.y, 1, 1)); // mouseLoc.y is flipped
NSBitmapImageRep* bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:image];
CGImageRelease(image);
NSColor* color = [bitmap colorAtX:0 y:0];
NSLog(@"%@", color);
```

Comment: You are correct that the mouse location needs to be flipped. However, you have to do that for the call to `CGGetDisplaysWithPoint()`, too. To get the screen height properly, use `NSHeight([NSScreen.screens.firstObject frame])`. For benefit of the OP, `NSPointToCGPoint()` only converts the point between two types. It doesn't adjust for the different coordinate systems.

Comment: Awesome! It works great. I didn't think about the co-ordinate system at all.